# How to solve access blocked by CORS policy (Tapkey Web API)

Tags: javascript, tapkey

When I try to connect to Tapkey Web API with Client Credentials, I get the following error message:
*"Access to fetch at 'https://login.tapkey.com/connect/token' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled"*

My code is the following:

```
async function connection() {
    try{
        let response = await fetch('https://login.tapkey.com/connect/token', {
            method:'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                'client_id': 'myclient_id',
                'client_secret': 'myclient_secret',
                'scope': 'read:owneraccounts read:core:entities write:core:entities write:grants',
                'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
            })
            });
        return response;
    } catch(err){
        return err;
    }
};

async function main(){
    let result = await connection4();
    console.log(result);
};

main();
```

Have you a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you are using a Client Credential Client direct in browser. As the Client Secret can not be stored secretly there, this should not be done. Therefore it is not possible to configure CORS for these clients.

For browser authentication "Authentication Code Flow with PKCE" should be used. For these clients the CORS can be configured.